# KeyboardView resize issue when rotating

Tags: android, android-layout, android-softkeyboard

I use a keyboard view that is stretched to fit the width of the screen, where each key in a row takes 1/3 of the width

```
android:keyWidth="33%p"
android:keyHeight="@dimen/key_height"
```

To handle orientation changes on the fragment I set a new keyboard:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    // Required to force the keyboard to inflate correctly after a rotation
    KeyboardView keyboardView = (KeyboardView) getView().findViewById(R.id.keyboard);
    keyboardView.setKeyboard(new Keyboard(getActivity(), R.xml.keyboard_config));
}
```

This works fine. I now want to use a different keyHeight for portrait and landscape. When I add this, the height of the keys resizes correctly on orientation changes, but the keyboard does no longer fill the width of the screen in landscape

Calling keyboardView.invalidateAllKeys(); or invalidating the the view of the fragment did not solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by using a percentage value of key height, and recreating/re-inflating the keyboard in the onEvaluateFullscreenMode event.  Example below.

**XML**

```
<Keyboard xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          encoding="UTF-16"
          android:keyWidth="20%p"
          android:keyHeight="8%p"
    >
    :
    :
</Keyboard>
```

**Java**

```
@Override
public boolean onEvaluateFullscreenMode() {

    try {

        keyboardView.setKeyboard(new Keyboard(getActivity(), R.xml.keyboard_config));

    } catch (Exception e) {

        Log.e(TAG, "onEvaluateFullscreenMode: Failed to recreate keyboard.", e);
    }

    return this.isFullscreenMode();
}
```